# (Equivalent theory of) general relativity without general relativity language

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

Is there a formulation or theory of classical relativistic gravity yielding the same predictions as the standard General Relativity (when the predictions are expressed in GR-free language which presumably always can be done) but formulated or written following standard non-gravitational interactions, e.g., such as based on mathematical structures built on top of basic causal structure such as Minkowski space (besides the obvious embedding of the pseudo-Riemannian manifold in the space)?

Or, any set of assertions compatible with the prediction of GR as we understand them today (again, when expressed in a GR-free and purely physical language including background independence) necessarily leads to GR and the identification of gravity with spacetime?

Comment: When you say "on top of basic causal structure such as Minkowski space" do you mean a 4D Minkowski spacetime or are you allowing for higher dimensions as well? Also, could you be a bit more specific on what you consider to be "GR language"?

Comment: There is the ADM formalism of GR, do you mean something like that (basically you get differential equations for the time evolution of a time sliced hypersurface)

Comment: Einstein carton theory is build on  different geometry and has all the same predictions apart from what happens inside a black hole

Comment: Re "When you say...": Correct, 4D Minkowski as we observe it, and specifically avoiding the hypotheticals such as compactified additional dimensions, etc. By the GR language I mean the curved geometry and the structures built on top the curved geometry.

Re "There is the ADM...": I would consider the ADM formalism still very much the same thing conceptually as the conventional GR. Similar with other formulations such as in terms of tetrads, etc.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313620/how-do-we-know-that-gravity-is-spacetime-and-not-a-field-on-spacetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is discussed somewhat in Steven Weinstein's essay "Naïve Quantum Gravity", published in [*Physics Meets Philosophy at the Planck Scale: Contemporary Theories in Quantum Gravity*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NugSt4i2-KIC) (eds. Callender & Huggett, 2001).  He begins by noting that

> [a]n alternative way to conceive of gravity would of course be to follow the lead of other theories, and regard the gravitational field as simply a distribution of properties (the field strengths) in *flat* spacetime.<sup>*</sup>  What ultimately makes this unattractive is that the distinctive properties of this spacetime would be completely unobservable, because all matter and fields gravitate. In particular, light rays would not lie on the "light cone" in a flat spacetime, once one incorporated the influence of gravity. It was ultimately the unobservability of the initial structure of Minkowski spacetime that led Einstein to eliminate it from his theory of gravitation and embrace the geometric approach.

So it's perhaps more elegant to view GR as a theory of curved spacetime;  but could we get away with thinking about it as a weird non-linear field theory on Minkowski spacetime anyhow?  It's certainly possible in some circumstances;  famously, [Steven Weinberg's 1972 book on general relativity tries to eschew geometric thinking as much as possible,](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/wordpress/?p=529) viewing GR as a field theory that has the Equivalence Principle as a fundamental principle and showing how object such as the metric and curvature tensors can be thought of as arising from this principle.  It seems to me that this is not far off from the OP's idea in the second paragraph that "any set of assertions compatible with the prediction of GR as we understand them today (again, when expressed in a GR-free and purely physical language including background independence) necessarily leads to GR and the identification of gravity with spacetime", though Weinberg (in 1972) might have disputed the last part.

However, Weinstein notes that there are still a few problems with this approach:

> First, the "invisibility" of the flat spacetime means that there is no privileged way to decompose a given curved spacetime into a flat background and a curved perturbation about that background. Though this non-uniqueness is not particularly problematic for the classical theory, it is quite problematic for the quantum theory, because different ways of decomposing the geometry (and thus retrieving a flat background geometry) yield different quantum theories.  Second, not all topologies admit a flat metric, and therefore space times formulated on such apologies do not admit a decomposition into flat metric and curved perturbation. Third, it is not clear a priori that, in seeking to make a decomposition in the background and perturbations about the background, that the background should be *flat*. For example, why not use a background of constant curvature?

---

<sup>*</sup> Weinstein includes a footnote here which refers the reader to an "interesting philosophical analysis of this line of thinking" in Reichenbach's *The Philosophy of Space and Time (Eng. translation)*, (1958 [1927]).

Comment: This is starting to make sense, I will look into the references, thanks.

Basically, I was initially driven by thinking that it could be possible with non-zero probability to have the universe free of gravity and locally, far away from massive bodies, utterly built on top of flat spacetime (which would obviously be very different from ours, globally). Therefore, gravity is not an absolute necessity. However, based on what you referring to above, it appears it is not quite obvious or even true.

Comment: I tried to avoid mangling quantum physics into this (in particular, some relatively recent works proposing gravity as emergent from entanglement or dual to boundary quantum systems, at least in some cases) but, as Weinberg alludes to above, it may be wrong to ask the question without considering the quantum mechanics.