# What's the difference between the diffeomorphism invariance and reparametrization invariance?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, coordinate-systems, diffeomorphism-invariance

Can somebody tell me what's the difference between the diffeomorphism invariance and reparametrization invariance?

Comment: I always thought that these are the same things, except that "diffeomorphism invariance" is an annoying misuse of mathematical terminology (diffeomorphism is an isomorphism of smooth manifolds, and assuming that a theory makes sense on a smooth manifold is already assuming reparametrization invariance). I wonder if it is indeed so. One distinction one could try to make is that reparametrization invariance means that you can define the theory in a coordinate-free way on a manifold with some natural extra structure, while diffeomorphism means that the only structure is the smooth structure.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76721/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, see my answer below on why both notions are *slightly* less trivial than chart independence. (If you consider the statements I make about reparametrization invariance applied only to local charts, you do recover your statement that both amount to chart independence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Diffeomorphism Invariance**

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $\phi: M \to M$ be a diffeomorphism. A simple property of the Einstein equations is

$$
    g \in \otimes^2 TM \text{ is solution to vacuum Einstein equation} \implies \text{ so is } \phi^*g
$$

To see that this is true, simply pull back both sides of the Einstein equation by $\phi$, and use the property of the Ricci tensor $\phi^*Ric_{(g)} = Ric_{(\phi^*g)}$.

You have a family $[g] \equiv \{\phi^*g | \phi \in Diff^+(M)\}$ of Riemannian structures on your manifold which are supposed to describe the same physics. This what I would call the notion of diffeomorphism invariance in general relativity.

**Reparameterization Invariance**

A parametrization of one manifold $M$ by another manifold $N$ is a diffeomorphism $\varphi: M \to N$. $N$ parametrizes $M$ in the sense that a points $p \in M$ smoothly correspond points in $\varphi(p) \in N$.

Reparametrization invariance usually means a scenario where the choice of this diffeomorphism $\varphi \in Diff(M \to N)$ doesn't matter.

Here's a simple example of what people might call reparametrization invariance.

Take a smooth curve $\gamma: [0, 1] \to M$, and suppose that $\gamma$ solves the geodesic equation. 
Let $\gamma': [0, 1] \to M$ be another curve, we have the following (trivial) fact

$$
\text{ $image(\gamma') = image(\gamma)$  } \implies \gamma' \text{ is also a geodesic}
$$

that is, the geodesic equation (length functional, not energy functional) doesn't care how you parameterize your curve.

**Sometimes they're the same thing**

To summarize, so far, I've presented diffeomorphism invariance as a statement about Riemannian structures on a manifold, and reparametrization invariance as a statement about diffeomorphisms from one manifold to another. There are some scenarios where these seemingly different notions are really the same thing.

*Example 1: Curve Reparametrization*

Consider our description of diffeomorphism invariance applied to a $1$-manifold. Riemannian structures on $1$-manifolds are equivalent to reprarmetrizations of the curve. Pulling back the Riemannian inner product on the tangent bundle by a smooth map is equivalent to smoothly reparametrizing the curve. So our notion of diffeomorphism invariance and reparametrization invariance are the same thing.

*Example 2: Moduli Space of closed orientable surfaces*

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed orientable surface. Say we are interested in the space $Mod_{\Sigma, \mathbb R^n}$ of all submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ diffeomorphic to $\Sigma$.

One way to make this space explicit is to consider diffeomorphisms

$$e: \Sigma \to \mathbb R^n$$

But some of these diffeomorphisms map into the same submanifold in $\mathbb R^n$. These are exactly the diffeomorphisms related by a precomposition with diffeomorphism on the surface itself. Hence we have a description of our moduli space as equivalence classes of diffeomorphisms

$$
Mod_{\Sigma, \mathbb R^n} \simeq E \equiv \{e: \Sigma \to \mathbb R^n\}/\sim~~~ e \sim f \iff e = f \circ \phi ~~ \text{ for some } \phi \in Diff(\Sigma)
$$

Now give $\mathbb R^n$ the usual Euclidean metric $g_{\mathbb R^n}$. A diffeomorphism $e: \Sigma \to \mathbb R^n$ pulls back the metric to $\Sigma$ via $g_e \equiv e^*g_{\mathbb R^n}$. Observe:

$$
    g_{e \circ \phi} = (e \circ \phi)^*g = \phi^*g_e
$$

In particular, when $\phi \in Diff(\Sigma)$, this says pullbacks by homeomorphisms in the same equivalence class are related by pullbacks by homeomorphisms on the surface. Hence another equivalent description of moduli space is

$$
  Mod_{\Sigma, \mathbb R^n} \simeq F \equiv \{g \text{ metric on } \Sigma\}/\sim~~~ g \sim h \iff g = \phi^*h ~~ \text{ for some } \phi \in Diff(\Sigma)
$$

In summary, we found

$$
    Mod_{\Sigma, \mathbb R^n} \simeq E \simeq F
$$

Observe now

- The equivalence relation in $E$ is identification of homeomorphisms that have the same image. We would call this reparametrization invariance.
- The equivalence relation in $F$ is pullback of metric by diffeomorphisms on $\Sigma$. We would call this diffeomorphism invariance.

In other words, in this case diffeomorphism invariance is a manifestation of reparametrization invariance on the space of Riemannian metrics.