# Active and passive transformations in coordinate-free relativity

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, relativity, coordinate-systems

Consider a coordinate-free metric tensor $g$ which can take different coordinate forms, say $g_{ij}(x)$ and $g_{i'j'}(x')$. Also consider a metric tensor $h$ which is related to $g$ by an active transformation.

Questions (which really boil down to one):

1. Are the possible coordinate forms of $h$ the same as those of $g$? My understanding of all GR textbooks is that there is a duality between passive and active transformations and so the answer must be 'yes'.
2. Should $g_{ij}(x)$ and $g_{i'j'}(x')$ be considered different representations of the same object? Universally I have seen the answer 'yes'.
3. Should we consider $g$ and $h$ as fundamentally different metric tensors? I have always seen that the answer is 'yes'.
4. Does this mean that the set of coordinate representations of $g$ also represent $h$ and so the answer to 2 or 3 above should be 'no'?

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76721/the-role-of-active-and-passive-diffeomorphism-invariance-in-gr) seems to focus on whether or not we consider the metric tensor as a dynamical field. That is a physics point whereas I am asking a differential geometry point. Misner, Thorne and Wheeler don't mention actives until near the end. Wald and [Carroll](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll5.html) focus on the duality. [Norton](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00731880) makes a philosophical distinction referring to the hole argument. EDIT: I had misunderstood [Gaul and Rovelli's](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9910079) argument in that they are making a point about *metrics* in relation to *metric tensors*, pointed out by user12262.

Comment: Matta: Could you please confirm your (and Gaul/Rovelli's) choice of notation and terminology? Are $g$, $h$, etc. there really supposed to denote a [**metric (space)**, such as $d : X \times X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ (or possible generalizations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition), and not rather a [**metric tensor**, viz. $g : T_p \mathcal M \times T_p \mathcal M \rightarrow \mathbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Tangent_spaces_and_metric_tensors) ? ...

Comment: @user12262 You have cleared up one of my misconceptions, thank you very much. Hopefully the question is now properly defined. I am interested  in metric tensors, not metrics.